# VBA-1004 ERROR - Trying to copy to a Named Range - New to VBA

Tags: excel, vba, paste, named-ranges

new to VBA and trying hard to figure out what I'm doing wrong - i can't.  My code is below.  I keep getting the Run-time Error 1004 (Application defined or object defined error).

I have two conditions that have to be met before the cell value can be copied to the named range on sheet2.  Everything seems to go well until I want to copy it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
Sub MoveHrs()

Dim i As Integer 'Loop
Dim Wb As Workbook, Ws As Worksheet 'Set objects
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook 'workbook
Set Ws = Wb.Worksheets("NDE2018") 'Sheets
Dim Ws2 As Worksheet
Set Ws2 = Wb.Worksheets("Sheet2") '2nd worksheet

'loop through each cell
For i = 24 To Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row 'from row 24 to last cell with data

    If Ws.Cells(i, 3) > 0 And Ws.Cells(i, 3).Offset(0, -1) = "18liist" Then 'find hours and copy to appropriate named range in ws2
        Ws.Cells(i, 3).Copy Ws2.Range("LIIST18" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ElseIf Ws.Cells(i, 3) > 0 And Ws.Cells(i, 3).Offset(0, -1) = "18liiot" Then 'find hours and copy to appropriate named range in ws2
        Ws.Cells(i, 3).Copy Ws2.Range("LIIOT18" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

  End If
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False 'suppress the marching ants
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do but `Range("LIIST18" & Rows.Count)` be resolve as something like `Range("LIIST181000000")` as there are approx 1 million rows.

Comment: Is Range("LIIOT18" a named range?

Comment: Hello Davesexcel and thank you for responding - yes, Range( "LIIOT18") is a named range.  New to VBA and feel very lost.

Comment: Hello SJR - thank you for your response.  Range("LIIOT18") is a named range.   I'm wanting to paste to the last empty cell in the named range.  So i'm searching for any labor hours on sheet("NDE2018"), if the cell to the left of the hours is "18liist" then I want it to copy the hours to the next empty row on the next page in the named range.  Your help is greatly appreciated.